# Getting User input in letters for elsif

Tags: ruby

I have been trying to get user input to execute a code. I have trying to get user input in letters not number but not finding how to. Like below is sample code I try get user input using gets.chomp() but its giving an error. Is there a way to get through this?

```
puts  "Are you tall"
istall = gets.chomp()
puts "Are you male"
ismale = gets.chomp()

if
  istall == true
  ismale == false

  print "Hello Erica, Welcome"

elsif

  istall == false
  ismale == true

  print "Hello Nikola"

elsif

  istall == false
  ismale == false

print  "Hello Cathie"

elsif

  istall == true
  istall == true

  print "Hello Adam"


end
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code:

#### 1. Gathering input

`gets` returns a *string* but you expect a boolean. Therefore, you have to convert the input, e.g.:

```
istall = gets.match?(/yes|true/i)
```

The above uses a regular expression to check whether `gets` matches "yes" or "true". The result (a boolean) is then assigned to `istall`.

#### 2. Processing input

Your code

```
if
  istall == true
  ismale == false

  print "Hello Erica, Welcome"
end
```

is parsed as:

```
if istall == true
  # anything else
end
```

i.e. only the first condition is taken into account. To combine both conditions, you have to use `&&`:

```
if istall == true && ismale == false
  print "Hello Erica, Welcome"
end
```

or a little more succinct:

```
if istall && !ismale
  print "Hello Erica, Welcome"
end
```

#### Suggestions

For better readability, you should separate words by underscores, e.g.:

```
is_tall = true
is_male = false
```

You could put the people in an array, e.g. by creating a `Person` class via [`Struct`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Struct.html):

```
Person = Struct.new(:name, :tall, :male)

people = [
  Person.new('Erica', true, false),
  Person.new('Nikola', false, true),
  Person.new('Cathie', false, false),
  Person.new('Adam', true, true),
]
```

Now you can [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#find-method) a person meeting your criteria:

```
is_tall = true    # <- replace with actual user input
is_male = false

user = people.find { |person| person.tall == is_tall && person.male == is_male }
#=> #<struct Person name="Erica", tall=true, male=false>
```

and finally print a welcome message:

```
print "Hello #{user.name}, Welcome"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get char then use

```
char = STDIN.getc.chr
```

below is another way with your working script

```
puts  "Are you tall"
is_tall = gets.chomp()[0].downcase == "y"

puts "Are you male"
is_male = gets.chomp()[0].downcase == "y"

result =  
  if is_tall && !is_male
    "Hello Erica, Welcome"
  elsif !is_tall && is_male
    "Hello Nikola"
  elsif !is_tall && is_male
    "Hello Cathie"
  elsif is_tall && is_tall
    "Hello Adam"
  end
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

### Map you info

You can use a Hash to store your data:

```
people = { male: { tall: 'Adam', short: 'Nikola' }, female: { tall: 'Erica', short: 'Cathie' } }
```

### Define the way to interact with user

You need to get the answer from the user and validate it. This is one way using those methods:

```
def get_sex
  message = 'Is this person male?'
  get_user_input(message) ? :male : :female
end

def get_heigh
  message = 'Is this person tall?'
  get_user_input(message) ? :tall : :short
end
```

The methods above call a common method that loops and interact with the user, providing her with the information about the accepted answer:

```
def get_user_input(message)
  valid_answers = {true: ['y', 'yes', 'true'], false: ['n', 'no', 'false']}
  3.downto(1) do |n|
    puts "Valid answers are #{valid_answers[:true]} or #{valid_answers[:false]}."
    puts "(Default answer will be 'no' after #{n} times again."
    puts message
    user_input = gets.chomp
    return true if valid_answers[:true].include? user_input
    return false if valid_answers[:false].include? user_input
  end
  puts "Took 'no' as default answer\n\n"
end
```

### Make use of it

Finally, just get the name by calling

```
name = people[get_sex][get_heigh]
```

---

When you have more people, consider to use a different mapping, something like

```
people = [{ name: 'Adam', heigh: 190, sex: :male }, { name: 'Erica', heigh: 175, sex: :female }, ...
```

Of course accessing the data is a bit different, you should look at [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html) documentation (and also Array and Hash).

Comment: It's a good idea to store the people in a structured way. But having female names in hashes called `..._man` or short people in a hash called `tall_people` doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: @Stefan Yup! Not very clear indeed, requires a fix. Should be read like "..._man false so, woman". I leave the task to whom would like to follow this idea.

Comment: Maybe `people = { tall: { male: 'Adam', female: 'Erica' }, short: ... }` but that requires another mapping to fetch a person based on booleans.

Comment: @Stefan, good idea. Side mapping can be handled while validating the input. Don't you mind if I borrowed your idea and also `gets.match?(/yes|true/i)`? :)